# Kanji character looking different in different contexts

Tags: character-encoding, cjk

First noticed it when parsing and epub with a rudimentary java program, it does not seem caused by my program as within the same application, Calibre (ebook reader), the same character looks different in ebook HTML editing window and preview window: kanji different looks in Calibre ebook editor
[image]
The right look is the one of the preview window.
If I unpack the epub and open the html file for that page I get the character looking, more or less, like an I (or I itself).
If I paste the right looking kanji to MS word or libre office I still get the character looking like I. Extacting the font used in the epub and using it in word I still get the I-like character.
Can someone explain why this happen and how I can get the correct kanji in cut&paste or in the .html files resulting from unpacking the epub?

Comment: Are you using a font which overloads characters with other characters? I.e., your *actual* character is "I", but the font renders this character using a glyph which looks like 喻?

Comment: I have no knowledge of fonts overloading but your description seems right, the only place where I see the 喻 is Calibre preview window, everywhere else I see  "I".

Comment: Then that probably means you're using a weird font which does not correctly map the right characters to the right glyphs. In order to get the character 喻 in your document you should be writing the character 喻 in your source code, not the character "I".

Comment: You are saying that the mapping between character codes and glyphs is ... let's say unusual? 
Could that be intentional to protect the original ebook (even from cut&paste)?
I was trying to extract study info from an ebook, from  a java program, just to avoid manual typing info about several thousands CJK characters. 
The epub results from another ebook in protected format (for completeness: I bought both paper and electronic format, the latter just in the hope of saving hundreds of hours of manual input)

Comment: That's basically what I'm saying. The reason for this might range anywhere from "copy-protection" to space-optimisation to incompetence. It's hard to know.